# Change red pixels to blue in a bitmap

Tags: vb.net, bitmap

I want to change the `red` pixels to `blue`. The image is 24 bits `.bmp`. I am using `lockbits` because it is faster but the code doesnt find the red pixels!

Code:

```
Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap("path")
Dim pos As Integer
Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)
Dim bmpData As System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData = bmp.LockBits _
        (rect, Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        bmp.PixelFormat)
Dim ptr As IntPtr = bmpData.Scan0
Dim bytes As Integer = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height
Dim rgbValues(bytes - 1) As Byte
Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes)

For y = 0 To bmp.Height - 1
    For x = 0 To bmp.Width - 1
        pos = y * bmp.Width * 3 + x * 3

        If rgbValues(pos) = 255 And rgbValues(pos + 1) = 0 And rgbValues(pos + 2) = 0 Then
            rgbValues(pos + 2) = 255
            rgbValues(pos) = 0
        End If
    Next
Next

Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes)
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData)
bmp.Save("new path")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values that are stored in `rgbValues` are **not** in this order

```
R G B R G B.....
```

but

```
B G R B G R.....
```

so the correct code in your loop is:

```
'       B                      G                            R
If rgbValues(pos) = 0 And rgbValues(pos + 1) = 0 And rgbValues(pos + 2) = 255 Then
    rgbValues(pos + 2) = 0 'R
    rgbValues(pos) = 255 'B
End If
```

Comment: Wow! Fast answer. Let me check